# where do i find sonar's exclusion settings?

Tags: configuration, installation, sonarqube

I've upgraded from sonar 2.12 to sonar 4.5.2 all seems well, except the exclusions list which i can't remember.

so I've been trying to see where it kept them (not in sonar.properties), is it in the database? a separate file?

Answer (score 2):

Please check the [official SonarQube documentation on how to manage exclusions](http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/jAAW).

Comment: The doc explain on the exclusion. Not how to migrate it from different versions